# C# - Server.MapPath();

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error the name "server" does not exist on current context. 
Tengo este codigo donde mandare una descarga dependiendo del boton que se presione, pero la palabra Server me marca el error.

```
public FileResult DownloadiOS()
        {
            var rutaios = Server.MapPath("~/Registro-pmm.ipa");
            return File(rutaios, "application/ipa", "DescargaiOS.ipa");
            //return View();
        }

        public FileResult DownloadAndroid()
        {
            var rutaandroid = Server.MapPath("~/Registro-pmm.apk");
            return File(rutaandroid, "application/apk", "DescargaAndroid.apk");
            //return View();
        }
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Server es una propiedad del controlador
Podes usar

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server
```

Saludos

Comment: Ok, pero ahora me marca error toda la parte de "System.Web.HttpContext", tengo el using System.Web;

Comment: @ISC.Villegas cuando haces el using te marca la referencia como que hay error? si no la agregaste, agregala desde el projecto --> add reference / agregar referencia

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones por si quieres una ruta relativa del servidor es utilizar `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ruta")`

Saludos